# How to hide the carrier name in status bar?

Tags: notification-bar, carriers

I'm using MIUI rom and in the Philippines, the carrier name is pretty long. "Globe Telecom-P" and it takes up a lot of status bar space. Gah. Is there a way to hide this?

Comment: As far as I remember, [Phono](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infonetservice.phono) can replace the carrier name with a logo. Maybe you could give that a try and report back? If it does solve your issue, I will make it a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It doesn't seem to work. I can see my carrier's logo come up like a standard notification, but like a standard notification, it goes away, too. I wonder why it's working pretty well in the screenshots.

Comment: It's quite a while ago I used it last time. It's icon went to the very left of the navigation bar. I last used it on Gingerbread... Have you checked its settings? According to its [tips & tricks section](http://phonoins.blogspot.de/p/tips-triks.html), there's an option to hide the icon from the status bar. Other hints to find there as well. Could also be a device specific problem, so you might want to contact the dev.

Comment: Hmmm. I think Phono works but there's a problem with my ROM. It's a new beta one, I forgot to add. I now remember in older ROM versions when there are notifications that you set to show persistently on the status bar, it would stay there and stay over the carrier but now the carrier name gets priority. It happens with other app notifications, too.

Comment: In that case, the issue is better addressed in the ROMs forum. The devs should know what they changed, and whether/where there's an option to adjust that behaviour.

Comment: Phono can address my original problem, but the carrier name being persistently on the status bar is the ROM issue. I mean, if it was on a good ROM, Phono would definitely answer my question. So if you can add it as an answer, I'll mark it :)

Comment: Done -- thanks! Good luck, hopefully the next Beta of your ROM fixes that -- or you might try a different ROM :)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, sooner or later it will get fixed. I can live with this issue for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Phono](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infonetservice.phono) is able to replace the carrier's name with a logo:

[image: Phono]
<sup>Phono (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infonetservice.phono); click image to enlarge)</sup>

Take a look at above screenshot. See the T logo in the upper left, on the notification bar? That's placed by *Phono*. It additionally offers a bunch of widgets to show you network strength and other things, plus some shortcuts (as shown in the screenshot).

I used *Phono* successfully on HTC stock ROMs as well as with CyanogenMod. Though your seem to have issues with your current Beta-ROM, those might hopefully be fixed with an update, so *Phono* will work on that, too -- otherwise it might still help you in case you decide to switch ROMs :)

Comment: On Moto X/4.4.2 at least, Phono adds a logo but the carrier text remains